# Google ics calendar feed fullday events

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar

I have a full day event which I want to export to my Google calendar via an ics file. The format of the ics file is as follows

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
TYPE:VCALENDAR

UID:xxx
PRODID:-//ABC//EN
X-PUBLISHED-TTL:1
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
X-WR-CALNAME:ABC TEST - Calendar

BEGIN:VEVENT
TYPE:VEVENT

UID:xxx
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:Full day event

DESCRIPTION:

TRANSP:TRANSPARENT

DTSTART:20130910T000000Z

DTSTAMP:20130909T235959Z

DTEND:20130910T000000Z
```

I am facing 2 problems

1. In Google this event does not show up as a full day event i.e. It shows up as a normal event
2. How do I remove the time from the event i.e. Its a full day event but showing up as starting at 5:30 am . I am in the Indian Timezone UTC +5:30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the DATE format of [RFC5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.4)

In your case, that would be

```
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20130910
```

On the other hand, you do not need a DTEND.

You should also remove those TYPE properties ("TYPE:VCALENDAR" and "TYPE:VEVENT") which are not valid.

Finally, the first UID property (the one directly under TYPE:VCALENDAR) is not valid there. Only the second one is valid and required.